# Mongo compound index is not chosen

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have the following schema:

```
{
    score  : { type : Number},
    edges : [{name : { type : String }, rank  : { type : Number }}],
    disable : {type : Boolean},
}
```

I have tried to build **index** for the following query:

```
db.test.find( {
    disable: false, 
    edges: { $all: [ 
        { $elemMatch: 
            { name: "GOOD" } ,
        }, 
        { $elemMatch: 
            { name: "GREAT" } ,
        }, 
    ] }, 
}).sort({"score" : 1})
.limit(40)
.explain()
```

**First try**

When I created the **index** name "score" :

```
{
    "edges.name" : 1,
    "score" : 1
}
```

The 'explain' returned  :

```
{ 
  "cursor" : "BtreeCursor score",
  ....
}
```

**Second try**

when I changed "score" to:

```
{
    "disable" :  1,
    "edges.name" : 1,
    "score" : 1
}
```

The 'explain' returned :

```
 "clauses" : [ 
    {
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor name",
        "isMultiKey" : true,
        "n" : 0,
        "nscannedObjects" : 304,
        "nscanned" : 304,
        "scanAndOrder" : true,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "indexBounds" : {
            "edges.name" : [ 
                [ 
                    "GOOD", 
                    "GOOD"
                ]
            ]
        }
    }, 
    {
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor name",
        "isMultiKey" : true,
        "n" : 0,
        "nscannedObjects" : 304,
        "nscanned" : 304,
        "scanAndOrder" : true,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "indexBounds" : {
            "edges.name" : [ 
                [ 
                    "GOOD", 
                    "GOOD"
                ]
            ]
        }
    }
],
"cursor" : "QueryOptimizerCursor",
....
}
```

Where the 'name' index is :

```
{
    'edges.name' : 1
 }
```

Why is the mongo refuses to use the 'disable' field in the index?
(I've tried other fields too except from 'disable' but got the same problem)

Comment: That index was optimal, with `n` = `nscanned`, so I guess it won when the query optimizer raced it against other plans. What do the explains look like for the other plans? `.explain(true)` will show you how all the query plans compared to each other.

Comment: `n` is actually 0. But when executing `explain(true)` I get higher `nscanned` for the "score" index.

Comment: Whoops. Shifted the numbers down one so I read `n` = `nscanned` when `nscanned` = `nscannedObjects`. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the query optimiser is choosing the most efficient index and the index on `edges.name` works best. I recreated your collection by inserting a couple documents according to your schema. I then created the compound index below.

```
db.test.ensureIndex({
    "disable" :  1,
    "edges.name" : 1,
    "score" : 1
});
```

When running an explain on the query you specified, the index was used.

```
> db.test.find({ ... }).sort({ ... }).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor disable_1_edges.name_1_score_1",
    "isMultiKey" : true,
    ...
}
```

However, as soon as I added the index on `edges.name`, the query optimiser chose that index for the query.

```
> db.test.find({ ... }).sort({ ... }).explain()
{
"cursor" : "BtreeCursor edges.name_1",
"isMultiKey" : true,
...
}
```

You can still hint the other index though, if you want the query to use the compound index.

```
> db.test.find({ ... }).sort({ ... }).hint("disable_1_edges.name_1_score_1").explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor disable_1_edges.name_1_score_1",
    "isMultiKey" : true,
    ...
}
```

[EDIT: Added possible explanation related to the use of `$all`.]

Note that if you run the query without `$all`, the query optimiser uses the compound index.

```
> db.test.find({
        "disable": false,
        "edges": { "$elemMatch": { "name": "GOOD" }}})
    .sort({"score" : 1}).explain();
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor disable_1_edges.name_1_score_1",
    "isMultiKey" : true,
    ...
}
```

I believe the issue here is that you are using `$all`. As you can see in the result of your explain field, there are clauses, each pertaining to one of the values you are searching with `$all`. So the query has to find all pairs of `disable` and `edges.name` for each of the clauses. My intuition is that these two runs with the compound index make it slower than a query that looks directly at `edges.name` and then weeds out `disable`. This might be related to [this](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-16042) issue and [this](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5331) issue, which you might want to look into.

Comment: I tried `hint` and `explain(true)` as suggested above, and found out that the `nscanned` for `score` is 10 times higher than the `name` index. Any idea why it works better without the `disable`. How the index for sub-documents array works?

Comment: @skme , I've added a possible explanation related to the presence of the `$all` operator.

Comment: That's an interesting observation. We actually found that it's better to use `"$and" : [
{"edges.name": "GOOD"},
{"edges.name" : "GREAT"},
]`